# How do I display the date only once but have a tick every few hours in ggplot?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, dplyr, posixct

Here is the dataset in question

```
z <- read.csv(text="order_dates,Value
2022-08-28 00:00:10,80.9 
2022-08-28 00:16:40,81.6   
2022-08-28 00:33:28,81.2
2022-08-28 05:37:12,81.4
2022-08-29 08:52:24,89.0    
2022-08-29 09:50:28,100.6   
2022-08-29 12:30:08,84.9")
z$order_dates <- as.POSIXct(z$order_dates)
```

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=z, aes(x=order_dates, y=Value), lwd = 0.5, alpha = 0.6) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours", date_labels = "%m/%d %H:%M")
```

This code results in the date being displayed on every tick. As previously stated, I would like for it to be shown only once per day -- and a tick for every 2 hours.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `labels =` instead of `date_labels =`, you can specify a labelling function that takes date times and formats them however you please. You could use this to convert any date-times that aren't at midnight to time strings, and use your desired date-time format otherwise:

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=z, aes(x=order_dates, y=Value), lwd = 0.5, alpha = 0.6) + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours", 
                   labels = ~ ifelse(substr(.x, 12, 19) == '00:00:00', 
                                     strftime(.x, "%H:%M\n%m/%d"),
                                     strftime(.x, '%H:%M')))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to keep the time instead of having the ticks being blank?

Comment: @EV_Mustang sure, just use `strftime` to specify the format instead of a blank string. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `date_breaks` function from `library` `scales`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
z <- read.csv(text="order_dates,Value
2022-08-28 00:00:10,80.9 
2022-08-28 00:16:40,81.6
2022-08-28 00:33:28,81.2
2022-08-28 05:37:12,81.4
2022-08-29 08:52:24,89.0
2022-08-29 09:50:28,100.6
2022-08-29 12:30:08,84.9")
z$order_dates <- as.POSIXct(z$order_dates)

ggplot() +
geom_line(data=z, aes(x=order_dates, y=Value), lwd = 0.5, alpha = 0.6) +
scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%m/%d %H:%M",breaks = date_breaks("2 hours"))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0))
```

[image]